# Django-summernote image's shape functions

Tags: javascript, django, summernote

I'd been using django-summernote v.0.6.16 and after update to v.0.8.2 I found that image's functions such as shapeThumbnail,shapeCircle and shapeNone had disappered.

Is the way to customize those functions in image's popover variable? or were those functions deprecated and removed?

Googling it didnt give me answer.